# TableView with multiple sections swift

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, uitableview, multidimensional-array

I have created a tableview with two sections using storyboard.
I want to be able to display different items for each section using array of arrays and be able to delete each row individually. 
I tried the following but the app crashes

```
import Foundation
import UIKit
var  letters: [String] = []
class NotificationsViewController: UITableViewController {




   var  data = [ letters, ["1","2","3"]]



    override func viewDidLoad() {



        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.tableView.editing = true

    }


  override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
  //return letters.count
     return data[section].count

    }

    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell: UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: "tableCell")

       // cell.textLabel?.text = letters[indexPath.row]
          cell.textLabel?.text = data[indexPath.section][indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }



    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        if editingStyle == .Delete {
//            // Delete the row from the data source
//            letters.removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
//           
//            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: .Fade)

            data[indexPath.section].removeAtIndex(indexPath.row)
            tableView.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Automatic)



        }
    }


}
```

This is my tableViewController: 
[screeshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h8EHF.png)

Error :

2016-05-10 17:01:48.278 App[70893:6874230] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:

the app works fine when I have one array such as the letters array and it will display the same data in both sections

Comment: You will have to provide sufficient information for us to understand the problem. What is the error you see when the app crashes? Is this the complete source for your TableViewController?

Comment: yes, this is the complete source.Error :                                                                                                            2016-05-10 02:54:39.757 App[67795:6715726] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:

Answer (score 0):

You can try removing letters and replacing data as follows:

```
var  data = [["1","2","3"]]
```

and if you want multiple sections something like this:

```
var  data = [["1","2","3"], ["4","5"]]

override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return data.count
}

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    return 20
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I found my problem.
It was because I had one row for each section in my tableview. Once I added more rows, the app worked and did not crash.